# Error when assigning ggplot to variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use `grid.arrange`and am thus assigning my plots to variables.
Plotting my data as a scatter plot works perfectly fine.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=log(x), y=log(y), color=Category))+ geom_point()
```

But when I assign this to a variable I get an error message

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=log(x), y=log(y), color=Category)) + 
     geom_point()

g

Error: unexpected numeric constant in "g 1"
```

Why is this the case?

Best Regards
Pete

Comment: Does it persist in a fresh R-session? I could not replicate your error with sample data. If it persists in a new R-session, can you post a dput of the data?

Comment: I made 2 changes: I replaced my ÿ with y in "Category" and set up a dataframe only with the needed data `tempframe=data.frame(Category=df$Category, x=df$x, y=df$y, stringsAsFactors = F)` and it works

Comment: Good that it works. For any future questions, consider reading up on how to create a [reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), makes it easier for others to help you.